# How do I solve the error about encoding ？

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1025626909" ofType:@"txt"];
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSError *error;
NSString *pageSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
NSLog(@"==%@",pageSource);
NSLog(@"==%@",[error description]);
```

above code output this：

```
2013-09-16 17:40:08.843 encodingTest[3350:c07] ==(null)
2013-09-16 17:40:08.846 encodingTest[3350:c07] ==Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 264.)" UserInfo=0x71a5af0 {NSFilePath=/Users/dayu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/A33DE8D6-D64B-4791-ADB6-1AB4B35B743A/encodingTest.app/1025626909.txt
```

I can't get the txt file's content，hope superman come help me 。。。。。

I find the file I found this file encoding is GB2312 by other means，then i used the kCFStringEncodingGB_2312_80 code . There is no effect 。。。

Comment: Do *you* know how the file is encoded? Can you show (a part of) the contents?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459-SW4.

Comment: thank ， i don't know the encoding of the file ,and I once tried according to what you said. But the question is still unsolved

Answer (score 4):

Error 264 means `NSString` couldn't determine the encoding of the file; therefore *you* need to tell *it* what the encoding is, which is probably UTF-8:

```
NSString *pageSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:&error];
```

In order to find what Error 264 means I looked in `FoundationErrors.h`:

```
NSFileReadUnknownStringEncodingError NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0) = 264, // Read error (string encoding of file contents could not be determined)
```

Which I found in my Xcode app contents using the `find` command:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
$ find . -name \*.h -exec fgrep -l 264 {} \;
./Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAssetExportSession.h
(lots of others deleted)
./Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/FoundationErrors.h
```

Comment: @user2749311 I don't understand why you don't know the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the parameter of usedEncoding may use NSUTF8StringEncoding,then you may get the txt file's content.

Comment: Your answer appears to be kind fo comment, as you are jsut guessing and can't say it surely. So this is not a answer in view of SO.

Answer (score 0):

let me tell why。。。because I hope NSLog all content of the txt file once. That always return null. so I take a small part of the txt file ，then I get the right content 。。。You know, when I see this  result I was very happy .
NSStringEncoding enc2 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);
 NSString *textFile  = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:enc2 error:&error];